# Is there a chart/ timeline of prophecies made by Jeremiah and their fulfilment?

Tags: prophecy, chronology, jeremiah, exile

I am reading Jeremiah, and would like to see a summary of the prophecies made by Jeremiah, and where/when/how they are/aren't (yet) fulfilled, with references to other books of the Bible, or historical evidence.

Does a chart or timeline like this exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group and your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Answer (score 1):

The book of the prophet Jeremiah is the longest book in the Bible, having more words than any other book. It also covers a complicated period of time in history so that anyone wanting to know what you seek to know would have to have that background clear in their mind. Without knowing that, there can be no way of working out what he foretold that came to pass in his lifetime, after he'd said it, and what did not happen until after his death. He is reckoned to have been a prophet from around 627 to 580 B.C. However, the date of his death is uncertain. According to ch.1 vss.2-3, that had to be some time after 586 B.C. There is a tradition that, while living in Egypt, he was stoned to death.

Here is a link giving a brief outline that might be helpful, although I cannot vouch for the veracity of this site, or the other two links provided further down. http://www.steppesoffaith.com/apologetics/jeremiah-prophecy

There is a helpful historic appendix, the last chapter of Jeremiah, added after a main prophecy came to pass (regarding the fall of Jerusalem on 18th July, 586 B.C. after a three year siege of the Babylonians during King Zedekiah's reign.) That shows how Jeremiah's main prophecy came to pass. But other prophecies related to the coming of Christ the Messiah, and the new covenant God would make, so not fulfilled in Jeremiah's lifetime.

Here is a list of some specific prophecies that were fulfilled in his lifetime -

16:15; 20:4; 25:11-14; 27:19-22; 29:10; 34:4-5; 43:10-11; 44:30; 46:13

https://uk.images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=AwrkOZIIpcdlSPk8iBJ3Bwx.;_ylu=Y29sbwMEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3Nj?p=jeremiah+prophecies+fulfilled+chart&type=Y143_F163_201897_102620&hsimp=yhs-001&hspart=trp&ei=UTF-8&fr=yhs-trp-001

Others that were fulfilled after his death or are yet still to be fulfilled -

23:5-5; 30:8-9; 31:31-34; 33:15-16

https://www.agapebiblestudy.com/charts/Jeremiah%27s%20Messianic%20Prophecies.htm

Comment: Thanks Anne! Will take some time to go through your response, with the references given. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lucy  You're welcome. Just don't assume that websites that provide helpful information about books of the Bible must be taken as sound and reliable for all else they claim. Lots of good sites can become misleading when they delve into interpretations of prophecies, for example.